# ¿Cómo evitar que la numeración vuelva empezar por cada nueva categoría?

Tags: php

Mediante mi código `PHP`

```
    //Busca todas las categorías en referencia de un producto por ejemplo: Capitulo 1, Capitulo 2, Capitulo 3
    $stmtChapters = $con->prepare("SELECT id_chapters,chapters FROM chapters WHERE id_video=?");
    $stmtChapters->bind_param("i",$id_video);
    $stmtChapters->execute();
    $stmtChapters->store_result();

    if ($stmtChapters->num_rows>0) {
        $stmtChapters->bind_result($id_chapters, $chapters);
        while ($stmtChapters->fetch()) {
            echo '<h1 class="chapters-player">'.$chapters.'</h1>';

            //Obtenemos todo los contenidos en base a la categoria por ejemplo se muestran 10 vídeos o textos en el Capitulo 1 y así sucesivamente en los otros capítulos.
            $stmtVideos = $con->prepare("SELECT title_video,format,multimedia,detail,url_website FROM videos WHERE id_video=? AND id_chapters=? AND active=?");
            $stmtVideos->bind_param("iii",$id_video,$id_chapters,$active);
            $stmtVideos->execute();
            $stmtVideos->store_result();

            if ($stmtVideos->num_rows>0) {
                $stmtVideos->bind_result($title_video, $format,$multimedia,$detail,$url_website);
                $i = 1;
                $mNav='<div id="enlaces" class="videolist">';
                $mDivs='<div id="ocultado" style="display: none;">';
                while ($stmtVideos->fetch()) {

                    if($format === 'video') {
                        $mNav.='<a class="link" href="'.$multimedia.'">
                                    <div class="panel-video">
                                        <span class="play-title">'.$title_video.'</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>';
                    }
                    if($format === 'html') {
                        $mNav.='<a class="link" href="'.$url_website.'">
                                    <div class="panel-video">
                                        <span class="play-title">'.$title_video.'</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>';
                    }

                    if($format === 'text') {
                        $mNav.='<a class="link" id="link_'.$i.'" href="#">
                                    <div class="panel-video">
                                        <span class="play-title">'.$title_video.'</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>';
                        $mDivs.='<div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_'.$i.'">'.$detail.'</div>';
                    }

                $i++;
                }
                $mDivs.='</div>';
                $mNav.='</div>';

                echo $mNav;
                echo $mDivs;

            } else {
                //
            }
        }
    } else {
        //
    }
```

Obtengo las categorías de los capítulos y en consiguiente también los productos o los datos enlazados al capitulo obteniendo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema exacto que presento es el siguiente justo en esta parte del código `PHP`

```
                    if($format === 'text') {
                        $mNav.='<a class="link" id="link_'.$i.'" href="#">
                                    <div class="panel-video">
                                        <span class="play-title">'.$title_video.'</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>';
                        $mDivs.='<div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_'.$i.'">'.$detail.'</div>';
                    }
                    $i++;
```

Debido a que aquella parte de código me imprime lo siguiente:

```
<div class="list-scroll-video">
    <h1 class="chapters-player">Capitulo 1</h1>
    <div id="enlaces" class="videolist">
        <a class="link" id="link_1" href="#">
            <div class="panel-video">
                <span class="play-title">Texto 1</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="link" id="link_2" href="#">
            <div class="panel-video">
                <span class="play-title">Texto 2</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="link" id="link_3" href="#">
            <div class="panel-video">
                <span class="play-title">Texto 3</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="link" id="link_4" href="#">
            <div class="panel-video">
                <span class="play-title">Texto 4</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="ocultado" style="display: none;">
        <div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_1">   DATOS DE TEXTO 1    </div>
        <div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_2">   DATOS DE TEXTO 2    </div>
        <div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_3">   DATOS DE TEXTO 3    </div>
        <div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_4">   DATOS DE TEXTO 4    </div>
    </div>

    <h1 class="chapters-player">Capitulo 2</h1>
    <div id="enlaces" class="videolist">
        <a class="link" id="link_1" href="#">
            <div class="panel-video">
                <span class="play-title">Texto 5</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="link" id="link_2" href="#">
            <div class="panel-video">
                <span class="play-title">Texto 6</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="link" id="link_3" href="#">
            <div class="panel-video">
                <span class="play-title">Texto 7</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="link" id="link_4" href="#">
            <div class="panel-video">
                <span class="play-title">Texto 8</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="ocultado" style="display: none;">
        <div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_1">   DATOS DE TEXTO 5    </div>
        <div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_2">   DATOS DE TEXTO 6    </div>
        <div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_3">   DATOS DE TEXTO 7    </div>
        <div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_4">   DATOS DE TEXTO 8    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Si ustedes observan en el **Capitulo 2**, se vuelve a repetir los id tanto en `<a class="link" id="link_1" href="#">` (`id="link_1"`) como en `div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_1"> DATOS DE TEXTO 1    </div>` (`id="c_link_1"`)

Al repetirse los números me causa un problema con el código `jQuery`, entonces para que sea más claro el resultado que debo y que debería obtener es el siguiente:

```
<div class="list-scroll-video">
    <h1 class="chapters-player">Capitulo 1</h1>
    <div id="enlaces" class="videolist">
        <a class="link" id="link_1" href="#">
            <div class="panel-video">
                <span class="play-title">Texto 1</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="link" id="link_2" href="#">
            <div class="panel-video">
                <span class="play-title">Texto 2</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="link" id="link_3" href="#">
            <div class="panel-video">
                <span class="play-title">Texto 3</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="link" id="link_4" href="#">
            <div class="panel-video">
                <span class="play-title">Texto 4</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="ocultado" style="display: none;">
        <div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_1">   DATOS DE TEXTO 1    </div>
        <div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_2">   DATOS DE TEXTO 2    </div>
        <div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_3">   DATOS DE TEXTO 3    </div>
        <div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_4">   DATOS DE TEXTO 4    </div>
    </div>

    <h1 class="chapters-player">Capitulo 2</h1>
    <div id="enlaces" class="videolist">
        <a class="link" id="link_5" href="#">
            <div class="panel-video">
                <span class="play-title">Texto 5</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="link" id="link_6" href="#">
            <div class="panel-video">
                <span class="play-title">Texto 6</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="link" id="link_7" href="#">
            <div class="panel-video">
                <span class="play-title">Texto 7</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="link" id="link_8" href="#">
            <div class="panel-video">
                <span class="play-title">Texto 8</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="ocultado" style="display: none;">
        <div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_5">   DATOS DE TEXTO 5    </div>
        <div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_6">   DATOS DE TEXTO 6    </div>
        <div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_7">   DATOS DE TEXTO 7    </div>
        <div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_8">   DATOS DE TEXTO 8    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Me pueden indicar que cambios debo realizar para obtener ese resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tienes dos loops anidados y en cada iteracion del primer loop inicializas la variable `$i = 1;`.  La solucion es sacar esa variable fuera del primer loop asi:

```
if ($stmtChapters->num_rows>0) {
        $stmtChapters->bind_result($id_chapters, $chapters);
        $i = 1;
        while ($stmtChapters->fetch()) {
            echo '<h1 class="chapters-player">'.$chapters.'</h1>';

            //Obtenemos todo los contenidos en base a la categoria por ejemplo se muestran 10 vídeos o textos en el Capitulo 1 y así sucesivamente en los otros capítulos.
            $stmtVideos = $con->prepare("SELECT title_video,format,multimedia,detail,url_website FROM videos WHERE id_video=? AND id_chapters=? AND active=?");
            $stmtVideos->bind_param("iii",$id_video,$id_chapters,$active);
            $stmtVideos->execute();
            $stmtVideos->store_result();

            if ($stmtVideos->num_rows>0) {
                $stmtVideos->bind_result($title_video, $format,$multimedia,$detail,$url_website);                    
                $mNav='<div id="enlaces" class="videolist">';
                $mDivs='<div id="ocultado" style="display: none;">';
                while ($stmtVideos->fetch()) {

                    if($format === 'video') {
                        $mNav.='<a class="link" href="'.$multimedia.'">
                                    <div class="panel-video">
                                        <span class="play-title">'.$title_video.'</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>';
                    }
                    if($format === 'html') {
                        $mNav.='<a class="link" href="'.$url_website.'">
                                    <div class="panel-video">
                                        <span class="play-title">'.$title_video.'</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>';
                    }

                    if($format === 'text') {
                        $mNav.='<a class="link" id="link_'.$i.'" href="#">
                                    <div class="panel-video">
                                        <span class="play-title">'.$title_video.'</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>';
                        $mDivs.='<div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_'.$i.'">'.$detail.'</div>';
                    }

                $i++;
                }
                $mDivs.='</div>';
                $mNav.='</div>';

                echo $mNav;
                echo $mDivs;

            } else {
                //
            }
        }
    } else {
        //
    }
```

Comment: Hola @alanfcm gracias por responder en estos momentos pruebo lo sugerido :)

Comment: Perfecto funciona perfectamente, no se como se puedo pasar por alto aquello, amigo una duda es posible poder agregar al final los contenedores de `id="cuadro"` así https://jsfiddle.net//6crpz7Lt/ tengo que mover aquello `$mDivs.='<div class="cuadro frame-scroll-multi-content" id="c_link_'.$i.'">'.$detail.'</div>';` pero esto creo que ocasionara otro gran problema si tiene alguna sugerencia se lo agradecería muchas gracias

Comment: Te refieres a los divs con `class="cuadro"`?  Que es lo que quieres mover o agregar?

Comment: Si exactamente aquello que van dentro de un contenedor `<div id="ocultado" style="display: none;"></div>` me gustaría poder tenerlos al final así https://jsfiddle.net//6crpz7Lt/ y no que se añadan debajo de cada capitulo es decir así no: https://jsfiddle.net/jtrmeqnv/ no se si tienes un tiempito en revisar la estructura HTML

Comment: Solo tienes que sacar el `echo $mDivs;` fuera de los 2 loops.